# Using Datagram in a Service in Android

Tags: android, service, datagram, forceclose

I am trying to write an Android application which receives a Datagram packet and plays that packet (audio packet).

I want to use a Service for this purpose so there is not interruption in the audio. For this I have a service like this:

```
public class MyService extends Service {
  ... 
  AudioTrack track;
  DatagramSocket sock;
  DatagramPacket pack;
  ...

  @Override
  public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    ...
    track = new AudioTrack(...)
    track.play();
    sock = new DatagramSocket(AUDIO_PORT);
    pack = new DatagramPacket(...)
    ...
    }

  @Override
  public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
    ...
    while(true)
    {
        try {
            sock.receive(pack);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        track.write(pack.getData(), 0, pack.getLength());
    }
  }
 }
```

In my main activity I have a "START" button which when it is pressed it runs:

```
startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
```

The app works fine and plays the received audio well, however after pressing the start button:

1. It does not respond to any other button
2. After a while I get this message: "Application MyAppName is not responding" and it gives two options `Forceclose` and `Wait`. If I press `Wait` the audo continues to play nicely but the UI is not responding anymore.

To me it looks like putting `while(true)` in the `onStart` may have caused this.

Any help and pointer in doing this in a correct way is appreciated.

Comment: `OnStart` should spawn another `Thread` or an `AsyncTask`. As is, it's taking over the UI thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example:

```
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
    ...
    Thread streamer = new Thread() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(true) {
                try {
                    sock.receive(pack);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                track.write(pack.getData(), 0, pack.getLength());
            }
        }
    });
    streamer.setPriority( Thread.MAX_PRIORITY );
    streamer.start();
  }
```

Obviously, in the final version of your code, you will want to keep track of the [Thread](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html) you create so that you can check its status or terminate it, and/or create a Handler in the thread so that you can control it from the service.

Comment: thanks for the  response. It looks like your suggestion resolves the initial message of `forceclose`. However to me it looks like now when I leave my app UI and open other apps I hear some clicks, while before the audio always was playing smoothly even when I open other apps. Is there a way to resolve this issue? Thanks again for the help.